# OpenLayers Get Opacity

Tags: openlayers-2, transparency-opacity

I understand how to set opactity to a map layer in OSM but how do you get the opacity?

Perhaps something like

```
layer.getOpacity()

OpenLayers.Util.getElement('opacity').value = layer.???
```

I have tried different combinations without success.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenLayers 2, opacity is a property, no need to use a function to get it :

```
  OpenLayers.Util.getElement('opacity').value = layer.opacity;
```

cf http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html